# Verificar ganhador de Jogo da Velha

Tags: java, algoritmo, jogos

O professor de algoritmo pediu para que a gente escrevesse um código para fazer um joguinho da velha simples no Java. E eu já tenho tudo pronto só que eu não estou muito feliz com a solução que eu arranjei pra validar quem venceu o jogo.

Eu fiz uma série de if e elseifs pra verificar cada condição em que um jogador pode vencer o jogo. E tudo bem, isso cobre o que o professor pediu, só que eu não acho que essa é a maneira mais inteligente de se escrever um algoritmo. Eu estava pensando em usar repetições encaixadas (for dentro de for) mas eu não consigo encontrar uma maneira onde eu posso aplicar isso no algoritmo, ou talvez de tanto pensar eu já não consigo pensar mais direito.

Eu também pensei em criar uma matriz com todas as possibilidades possíveis:

```
   final int[][][] condicoesVencer = {
    //COLUNAS
    {{ 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 }},
    {{ 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }},
    {{ 0, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2 }},

    //LINHAS
    {{ 0, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2 }},
    {{ 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 }},
    {{ 2, 0 }, { 2, 1 }, { 2, 2 }},

    //DIAGONAIS
    {{ 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }},
    {{ 2, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 2 }}
};
```

`condicoesVencer` guarda todas as possíveis combinações de vitorias, as posições do vetor `char tabuleiro[][] = new char[3][3]` onde o X ou o O podem vencer. Mas eu não consegui uma maneira de percorrer os dois vetores de forma a verificar no vetor tabuleiro cada condição no vetor `condicoesVencer` e agora eu não sei o que fazer.

Como substituir o monte de ifs que eu fiz em algo mais 'inteligente'? Por favor, se tiverem resposta, mandem o código e expliquem.

EDIT:
Aqui vai o método o que eu criei, com todos os ifs:

```
public boolean haGanhador(){
    //Checa X verticalmente
    if(tabuleiro[0][0] == 'X' && tabuleiro[1][0] == 'X' && tabuleiro [2][0] == 'X'){
        System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
        return true;
    }
     else if(tabuleiro[0][1] == 'X' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'X' && tabuleiro[2][1] == 'X'){
        System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
        return true;
     }
     else if(tabuleiro[0][2] == 'X' && tabuleiro[1][2] == 'X' && tabuleiro[2][2] == 'X'){
        System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
        return true;
    }



     //Checa X horizontalmente
     else if(tabuleiro[0][0] == 'X' && tabuleiro[0][1] == 'X' && tabuleiro[0][2] == 'X'){
    System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    else if(tabuleiro[1][0] == 'X' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'X' && tabuleiro[1][2] == 'X'){
    System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
    return true;
    } 
    else if(tabuleiro[2][0] == 'X' && tabuleiro[2][1] == 'X' && tabuleiro[2][2] == 'X'){
    System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    //Checa X diagonalmente
    else if(tabuleiro[0][0] == 'X' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'X' && tabuleiro[2][2] == 'X'){
    System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    else if(tabuleiro[0][2] == 'X' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'X' && tabuleiro[2][0] == 'X'){
    System.out.println("'X' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    //Checa O verticalmente
    if(tabuleiro[0][0] == 'O' && tabuleiro[1][0] == 'O' && tabuleiro [2][0] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    else if(tabuleiro[0][1] == 'O' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'O' && tabuleiro[2][1] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    else if(tabuleiro[0][2] == 'O' && tabuleiro[1][2] == 'O' && tabuleiro[2][2] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }

    //Checa O horizontalmente
    if(tabuleiro[0][0] == 'O' && tabuleiro[0][1] == 'O' && tabuleiro[0][2] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    else if(tabuleiro[1][0] == 'O' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'O' && tabuleiro[1][2] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    else if(tabuleiro[2][0] == 'O' && tabuleiro[2][1] == 'O' && tabuleiro[2][2] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }

    //Checa O diagonalmente
    if(tabuleiro[0][0] == 'O' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'O' && tabuleiro[2][2] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true;
    }
    else if(tabuleiro[0][2] == 'O' && tabuleiro[1][1] == 'O' && tabuleiro[2][0] == 'O'){
    System.out.println("'O' VENCEU");
    return true; 
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Que tal postar o seu código mesmo com o monte de IFs? Pode ajudar as pessoas interessadas em ajudar.

Comment: Acabei de postar

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61351/73

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Já que você prefere com poucos `IF`s, fiz uma solução usando um `IF` e um `FOR`apenas.

Solução:

```
public class JogoVelha {

    public static String obtemVencedor(String[] tabuleiro) {

        if ((tabuleiro == null) || (tabuleiro.length != 9)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                ("Um tabuleiro deve ser um array de 9 posições.");
        }
        Integer[][] padroesVitoria = {
                    {0, 1, 2},
                    {0, 4, 8},
                    {0, 3, 6},
                    {1, 4, 7},
                    {2, 5, 8},
                    {2, 4, 6},
                    {3, 4, 5},
                    {6, 7, 8}};

        for (Integer[] padraoVitoria: padroesVitoria) {

            boolean haVencedor = tabuleiro[padraoVitoria[0]] != null 
                && tabuleiro[padraoVitoria[0]].equals(tabuleiro[padraoVitoria[1]]) 
                && tabuleiro[padraoVitoria[0]].equals(tabuleiro[padraoVitoria[2]]);

            if (haVencedor) {
                String vencedor = tabuleiro[padraoVitoria[0]];
                return vencedor;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Teste:

```
@Test
public void jovadorXVence() {

    String[] tabuleiro = {
            "X", "O", null, 
            "O", "O", null,
            "X", "X", "X"} ;

    String vencedor = JogoVelha.obtemVencedor(tabuleiro);

    assertEquals("X", vencedor);
}

@Test
public void naoHaVencedor() {

    String[] tabuleiro = {
            "X", "O", null, 
            "O", "O", null, 
            "X", null, "X"} ;

    String vencedor = JogoVelha.obtemVencedor(tabuleiro);

    assertNull(vencedor);
}
```

Minha abordagem foi a seguinte:

- Percebi que o tabuleiro possui nove posições. Sua visualização seria algo assim:

  ```
  0 | 1 | 2
  ---------
  3 | 4 | 5
  ---------
  6 | 7 | 8
  ```
- Então o tabuleiro preenchido ou parcialmente preenchido por ser representado por um array de 9 posições.
- Então eu visualizei um exemplo de jogo terminado. Seria o seguinte:

  ```
  X | O | -
  ---------
  O | O | -
  ---------
  X | X | X
  ```
- Visualizando este jogo concluído dentro do meu array, eu identifiquei os padrões de vitória (quais posições dentro do array, quando ocupadas pelo mesmo jogador, sinalizam uma vitória):

  ```
  0 1 2
  0 4 8
  0 3 6
  1 4 7
  2 5 8
  2 4 6
  3 4 5
  6 7 8
  ```
- E então eu escrevi um algorítmo para processar o array representando um tabuleiro, procurando dentro dele os padrões de vitória.

Depois de cada jogada, `obtemVencedor` pode ser invocado para identificar se já há um vencedor. Se não houver vencedor, podemos verificar se ainda há posições disponíveis no tabuleiro (se há elementos não null no array) para saber se o jogo terminou empatado.

Comment: Ele já tinha o dever de casa feito :)

Comment: kkkk tudo bem. É que o professor pediu, especificamente, pra criar um array 3 por 3. Por isso eu fiz um `char tabuleiro[][] = new char[3][3]` , tambem achei que seria mais 'inteligente' fazer com um array de 9 posiçoes mas ele pediu desse jeito.
Gostei muito do modo de como vc resolveu, bastante interessante essa linha de raciocínio.

Comment: É verdade, @JorgeB!

Comment: @DavidDuque Well, se o professor queria a utilização de array multidimensional, neste algoritmo ele o tem, os padrões de vitória :-) Fazer do próprio tabuleiro um array multidimensional acho que daria mais trabalho.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar laços `for` para verificar ao final de cada rodada (a partir da terceira rodada) o vencedor, eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
1. Fora do for verifica diagonais são iguais
2. Verifica se linha i todas as colunas são iguais
3. Verifica se coluna i todas as linhas são iguais
```

codificando ficaria algo assim:

```
public boolean fimDoJogo(){
  if((matriDoJogo[0][0] == matriDoJogo[1][1] && matriDoJogo[1][1] == matriDoJogo[2][2]) || 
     (matriDoJogo[0][2] == matriDoJogo[1][1] && matriDoJogo[1][1] == matriDoJogo[2][0])){
    System.out.println("Venceu o jogador que escolheu o "+matriDoJogo[1][1]);
    return true;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(matriDoJogo[i][0] == matriDoJogo[i][1] && matriDoJogo[i][1] == matriDoJogo[i][2]){
      System.out.println("Venceu o jogador que escolheu o "+matriDoJogo[i][1]);
      return true;
    }
    if(matriDoJogo[0][i] == matriDoJogo[1][i] && matriDoJogo[1][i] == matriDoJogo[2][i]){
      System.out.println("Venceu o jogador que escolheu o "+matriDoJogo[1][i]);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Ainda seria possível alterar o retorno do método, para retornar qual símbolo de jogador venceu.

Comment: Como poderia fazer pra receber qual simbolo que satisfez a condição de vitoria?
Eu to começando ainda liga não a ignorancia kkkk

Comment: Você mudaria o cabeçalho pra `char` (poderia ser string também, mas é mais indicador char) e, ao invés de ter o system.out e return true, você teria `return matriDoJogo[x][y]`, onde x e y são os indíces conforme as condicionais. No caso, seria o que está sendo somada a string do System.out.

Answer (score 7):

Utilize mapas de bits (bitmaps).

Seu 'tabuleiro' pode ser expresso em uma sequência de bits, assim:

```
Posições
2 | 1 | 0
5 | 4 | 3
8 | 7 | 6
```

É equivalente a:

```
Posição 876543210
Bit     000000000
```

A seguinte condição de vitória

```
Posições
X |   |  
  | X |  
  |   | X
```

Pode então ser expressa da seguinte maneira:

```
001 010 100 = Decimal 84
```

Para verificar se o jogador alcançou essa condição, transforme as posições ocupadas por ele em um mapa binário também.

```
Posições
A | B |  
  | A | A 
B | B | A

Apenas jogador A
A |   |  
  | A | A 
  |   | A
```

Mapa de Bits:

```
001 011 100 = Decimal 92
```

Faça agora uma operação `AND` entre os dois:

```
001 010 100 AND
001 011 100 = 
001 010 100   Decimal 84
```

Se o resultado da operação AND for igual ao valor de condição de vitória, o jogador ganhou.

Crie um array com todas as condições de vitória possíveis:

```
Integer[] mapasVitoria = 
    {
    0b100100100, //Todas as posições da Coluna 1
    0b010010010, //Todas as posições da Coluna 2
    0b001001001, //Todas as posições da Coluna 3

    0b111000000, //Todas as posições da Linha 1
    0b000111000, //Todas as posições da Linha 2
    0b000000111, //Todas as posições da Linha 3

    0b100010001, //Diagonal Topo esquerdo -> Fundo direito
    0b001010100  //Diagonal Topo direito -> Fundo esquerdo
    };
```

e compare o mapa de bits de cada jogador a cada lance.

Comment: Bacana usar mapa de bits. A lógica é a mesma que a minha utilizando array de String e array de Integer, certo?

Comment: @Caffé correto, na prática é o mesmo processo de avaliação - talvez um pouco mais econômico no ponto de iterações necessárias para determinar um vencendor (apenas um ciclo, apenas uma operação AND por item, e assim por diante.) Por isso você levou um +1. =)

Answer (score 1):

Olha a forma mais simples que eu acho que você pode resolver este problema é toda é com este código:

```
possibilidades = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{6,4,8}}

for (p: possibilidades)
    if(tabuleiro[p[0]] == (tabuleiro[p[1]] == (tabuleiro[p[0]] && tabuleiro[p[0]] != null )
        System.out.println("Venceu");
```

Considerando que:

1 - Você inicializou um vetor de 9 posições com valor null (tabuleiro)

2 - toda vez que ocorre uma jogada você valida se venceu

As possibilidades é o mapa das jogadas válidas, todas as posições de uma possibilidade devem estar iguais (X/O) e diferente de null que é o valor inicial do mapa.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Este solução é quase igual à minha. Com a diferença que deixa sem resposta a pergunta: quem venceu?