# Como nomear um teste unitário quando utilizamos TDD?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, testes, tdd, convenções-de-nome

É comum utilizarmos substantivos para nomearmos: classes (Carro, Veiculo, NotaFiscal); verbos de ação (no infinitivo ou não) para nomes de métodos (CalcularTotal/CalculaTotal, LerTodasAsLinhas, FecharConexao, AbrirPorta/AbrePorta); interrogações para retornos booleanos (Enable, MustCalculate, ShouldDoSomething, EstaAberta, DisparouExcecao, EstaGravado, EstaAtivo). Essas são recomendações da OMG (para UML).

Porém, e quanto aos testes unitários? Existe algum padrão, guia para nomear os teste unitários?

A seguir, alguns exemplos de nomes que encontrei em alguns códigos que já tive contato:

- **Deve_retornar_zero**: não diz a situação, nem o motivo, e nem o que está sendo testado, apenas mostra o comportamento desejado.
- **Nao_deve_ter_sobre_nome_ao_informar_...**: tenta descrever um comportamento, mas esse nomes geralmente ficam bem grandes.
- **IntParse**: nesse caso, é um teste para o método Parse(...) da classe Int.

Já vi nomes separados por *underline*, sem separação, mas escritos em camelcase, e muitas outras formas.

A minha dúvida é: existem guias/sugestões de melhores práticas para nomearmos testes unitários quanto utilizamos TDD?

Comment: Ao que tudo indica você já conhece vários "padrões". A resposta do @reinert esboça a minha forma pessoal também, de todas as outras formas que já usei ( as que você citou ) achei esta mais objetiva. Só um adendo, seja consistente. Se escolher uma forma use-a até o final converse com o seu time e decida isso junto com eles. Não se esqueça que TDD vai muito além disso, então seja significativo nos nomes, se conseguir isso, o padrão de nomenclatura passará a ser apenas um coadjuvante.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sua pergunta trata de dois aspectos da nomeação de métodos; semântica e formatação, por assim dizer (classificações que me ocorreram agora).

### Formatação

A questão da formatação é simples:

- **faca_alguma_coisa()**
- **facaAlgumaCoisa()**
- **FacaAlgumaCoisa()**

A formatação é convencionada pelo time e é fácil de compreender e de manter. Eu sempre proponho ao time identificar a cultura da linguagem e seguir esta cultura. Por exemplo, em java utiliza-se muito o *lowerCamelCase*, diferente do C#, onde utiliza-se mais o *UpperCamelCase* para nomes de métodos, que é diferente de Ruby, onde utiliza-se *lower case* com *underline* como separador. Mas a decisão final é do time e um analisador automático de código pode identificar fácil o código que não estiver seguindo a convenção.

O que é mais importante aqui sobre a **formatação** é que **não existe uma convenção para o TDD**. Existe sim uma convenção para o time ou para o projeto. Todo o código deve seguir a convenção, seja o código de produção ou o código de testes.

### Semântica

Como sabemos, o nome de um método deve revelar o seu comportamento, e deve obeder a linguagem de negócio (quando ele tratar de negócio). E a assinatura do método deve garantir a abstração de como o método trabalha. A assinatura deve revelar ao consumidor tudo que ele precisa saber sobre o método sem precisar olhar o código dentro dele.

> O código dos testes unitários tem um conceito diferente. O nome de um
> método de teste unitário não tem que revelar com precisão o
> comportamento que ele espera, tampouco tem que revelar as condições,
> entradas e saídas (*"when..given.then"*)!

Embora o nome do método tenha que ser significativo, é o corpo dele, o código dentro, que vai descrever as condições, entradas e saídas esperadas.

Veja [este exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35225/14584):

```
public class JogoVelhaTeste {
    @Test
    public void naoHaVencedor() {

        String[] tabuleiro = {
                "X", "O", null, 
                "O", "O", null, 
                "X", null, "X"} ;

        JogoVelha jogoVelha = new JogoVelha();

        assertNull(jogoVelha.obtemVencedor(tabuleiro));
    }
}
```

Quando eu quiser saber **o que determina se não há vencedor**, o nome do método me permite encontrá-lo entre os outros, mas para saber de fato qual entrada determina que não há vencedor (no caso, um tabuleiro com determinadas jogadas), e para saber como é retornada a informação de que não há vencedor (no caso, o método *obtemVencedor* retorna *null*), eu olho o código dentro do método.

Assim, o próprio código dentro do método é a documentação das condições, entradas e saídas. E é uma documentação executável! Nunca estará desatualizada, como pode ocorrer com os comentários.

O artigo do [Roy Osherove](https://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html) dá umas dicas bacanas, mas você não precisa de um método chamado `Sum_NumberIgnoredIfBiggerThan1000`. Seria melhor chamar de `Sum_NumberIgnoredWhenTooBig`, que provavelmente é suficientemente significativo. As entradas, como eu disse, estão descritas no póprio código dentro do método.

### O teste não deve depender de comentários

[Neste exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jsocha/how-to-name-test-methods), o autor sugere um comentário para descrever o teste. Ok, não é um simples comentário; é atributo .Net! Mas no final não passa de um comentário, que não compila, que não afeta o funcionamento do teste, e que pode ficar desatualizado, e que só vai ser lido como última opção do desenvolvedor quando ele estiver procurando por um teste em código antigo (assim como o desenvolvedor também pode ler o código dentro do método).

Veja:

```
[TestMethod]
[Description("Given two tables And same data But different column order | When TableAssert | Then true")]
public void ColumnOrderDoesntMatter()
```

O nome deste método já é bastante significativo. Dispensa o comentário. As condições, entradas e saídas podem ser verificadas no corpo do próprio método, o qual o autor do exemplo não revela mas que bem pode ser algo assim:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ColumnOrderDoesntMatter() {
    
    Table tableAscValues = new Table("value 1", "value 2");
    Table tableDescValues = new Table("value 2", "value 1");
    
    Assert.Equals(tableAscValues, tableDescValues);
}
```

Trazer de volta o comentário (*Description*) para o método acima seria redundante.

### Behavior Driven Development (BDD)

BDD é diferente de nomear o método no estilo *when..given. then*. BDD trata-se de escrever testes com esta semântica utilizando uma linguagem executável. Então, assim como no meu exemplo (que não é BDD), é o corpo do método de testes que diz as condições, entradas e saídas, e não o nome do método.

### Escolhendo um nome de método de testes usando TDD

Em TDD escrevemos o teste primeiro. Muitas vezes ainda não sabemos como será o design da solução - ele vai emergir a partir dos testes. Então pode ser muito difícil escolher imediatamente um bom nome para o teste. Não tem problema. Escolha um nome qualquer que revele mais ou menos a intenção do que você quer testar, depois escreva mais alguns testes, depois revisite todos os métodos recém criados e os refatore, inclusive melhorando seus nomes.

### Conclusão

- O formato do nome do método de testes (*lower camel case*, *underline*...) deve seguir as mesmas regras do código de produção. Estas regras são convencionadas pelo time.
- O nome do método de testes deve ser significativo, deve descrever sobretudo o comportamento de negócio que se está testando; mas as condições, entradas e saídas são descritas pelo código dentro do teste. Um método de testes não tem o mesmo tipo de abstração que devem ter os métodos dos objetos de negócio.
- O corpo do método de testes é a documentação executável do comportamento do sistema.

Answer (score 5):

Há gosto para tudo, nunca vi um padrão universalmente aceito. [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101) coloquei padrões de nomenclatura bem aceitos porque basicamente foi estabelecido pela empresa criadora da linguagem C#, fazendo as devidas ressalvas. Neste caso acho mais complicado.

Para TDD, o qual eu tenho pouco experiência, dependendo da linguagem pode ter pequenas diferenças de padrão mas acho que o que você quer saber é algo que pode ser aplicado para todas as linguagens salvo diferenças estilísticas de usar maiúsculo, minúsculo, sublinhado, etc.

Já vi recomendações diferentes. Uma delas é descrever o que se espera que este teste representa de forma bem sucinta. Outra é descrever exatamente o que e como o método testa.

Particularmente a primeira me parece ser mais sensata. Os primeiros exemplos que citou parecem usar a segunda forma que eu citei. Sei que muita gente usa assim. Mas parece ser um caso das pessoas copiarem uma forma estabelecida no passado mas que ninguém pensou muito se faz sentido ou não. Já falei muitas vezes que isto ocorre muito na nossa indústria. Tem gente que ainda segue recomendações dos anos 50. Claro que algumas ainda podem ser válidas, mas não todas. Talvez era assim porque as ferramentas não eram boas. E talvez algumas ainda não sejam.

Então deve-se tentar entender porque o método *deve retornar zero* e descrever a motivação do teste. Deve-se usar um contexto. Quem vai dizer que deve retornar zero é o código.

Algumas linguagens permitem ainda ter um atributo/anotação que permite dar uma descrição detalhada do que o teste faz. Seria um comentário que a ferramenta vai aproveitar para ajudar descrever o teste quando ele rodar. Ex.:

```cs
[TestMethod]
[Description("Given two tables And same data But different column order | When TableAssert | Then true")]
public void ColumnOrderDoesntMatter()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/NamingTest.cs).

O exemplo foi retirado [dessa página](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031090039/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2012/03/11/how-to-name-test-methods.aspx). Nela mostra como a forma detalhada de nomear o método é pior.

Acho que assim o programador está fazendo TDD de verdade. TDD deve demonstrar o que acontece no teste e não como é testado.

[Nessa outra página](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html) há uma análise da forma mais usada.

[Teste unitário é o termo errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/567879/101).

Answer (score 2):

Venho utilizando há bastante tempo o padrão **[UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior]** apresentado [nesse histórico artigo](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html) por Roy Osherove e citado [nessa respota](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594049/3568987).

Até hoje, ele vem se aplicando a todos os casos que me deparo. Claro que para isso é necessário habilidade do programador em modelar corretamente a unidade a ser testada, e se for o caso, redesenhar seu projeto para que este torne-se plausível. Inclusive, esse é um dos benefícios do TDD, [influenciar positivamente no design](http://www.thoughtworks.com/pt/insights/blog/using-tdd-influence-design).

Vale notar que este padrão descrito por Roy pode ser enxergado também da seguinte forma [When_Given_Then], induzindo-nos a desenvolver o nosso método de teste conforme a seguir:

```
UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior() {
    // Given
    // promova o estado sob teste...

    // When
    // acione a unidade de trabalho, ou o método...

    // Then
    // verifique o comportamento desejado...
}
```

Exemplo de teste de uma classe Foguete (com Mockito):

```
decolar_tanqueVazio_permanecerParadoExibindoAviso() {
    // Given
    foguete.esvaziarTanque(); // foguete é uma mock instance em escopo de classe

    // When
    foguete.decolar();

    // Then
    verify(foguete, never()).iniciarDecolagem();
    verify(foguete, atLeastOnce()).exibirAvisoTanqueVazio();
}
```