# Qual a diferença entre teste unitário e teste integrado?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, testes, testes-de-unidade, independente-de-linguagem, tdd

Qual a diferença entre **teste unitário** e **teste integrado**, seus benefícios e exemplos de um para o outro.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Teste Unitário

**Descrição:** É a forma de se testar unidades individuais de código fonte. Unidades podem ser métodos, classes, funcionalidades, módulos, etc. Depende muito do que é a menor parte que seu Software pode ser testado.

**Objetivo:** dos testes unitários é mostrar que cada unidade atende corretamente sua especificação.

**Exemplo:** testes automáticos criados para darem entradas e conferirem saídas a cada método, permitindo que se saiba que está funcionando de acordo com o esperado.

**Benefícios:** encontrar problemas o quanto antes, facilitam a mudança da unidade, simplificam a integração e melhoram a documentação.

> Teste Integrado

**Descrição:** É a forma de se testar a combinação das unidades em conjunto.

**Objetivo:** Nesse caso, a ideia é encontrar falhas na junção destas unidades. Pode ser que a classe X funcione bem sozinha, mas ao ser utilizada pela classe Y, ela deixe de funcionar.

**Exemplo:** Colocar todo o software para rodar e começar a usar diversas funcionalidades consideradas centrais no seu programa para confirmar que ele roda e as principais funcionalidades fazem o esperado.

**Benefícios:** além de testar funcionalmente, pode assegurar performance e confiabilidade. Ajudam a garantir que o trabalho de um desenvolvedor não está afetando o trabalho de outro e em equipes grandes isso pode fazer toda a diferença se forem realizados com frequência.

Comment: Depuraração de código pode ser considerado um teste unitário ?

Comment: Rogi93,  apesar de a depuração de código ser uma forma de encontrar um bug ou problema que você sabe que existe e corrigir o problema acaba não servindo como teste unitário. 

O teste de unidade deveria ser algo que você vai rodar repetidamente. Se o teste falhar, aí sim você vai depurar o código pra encontrar o problema e corrigir.

Answer (score 13):

Complementando a [resposta do Rodrigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115157/41113) com exemplos:

**Teste Unitário** (que os puristas gostam de chamar de "teste de unidade". Blorg!): você tem a seguinte função no seu sistema (super simplista):

```
def soma(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Em seus testes unitários você fará "afirmações" (*assertions*) para ter certeza de que sua função está funcionando como deve. Em Python:

```
assert soma(7, 1) == 8
assert soma(-1, -1) == -2
```

**Teste Integrado** (ou "teste de integração"): você tem as seguintes funções (novamente simplistas):

```
def soma(a, b):
    return a + b

def multiplicacao(a, b):
    return a * b

def minhaFuncaoNadaVer(a, b):
    return soma(
        multiplicacao(a, b),
        multiplicacao(a + b, b)
    )
```

Após você ter feito Testes Unitários para as funções `soma` e `multiplicacao`, agora você vai fazer um Teste de Integração da função `minhaFuncaoNadaVer`, afinal ela integra duas funções do seu sistema (`soma` e `multiplicacao`). Em Python:

```
assert minhaFuncaoNadaVer(12, 6) == 180
assert minhaFuncaoNadaVer(1, 90) == 8280
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos começar explicando a confusão dos termos, primeiro o tal "teste unitário".

Ele é um erro linguístico e não existe de fato, ainda que grande parte das pessoas o chamem assim. Até pode existir, mas seria um teste com pouca serventia. Teste unitário é um teste único não vejo vantagem em fazer um único teste, queremos testar várias coisas.

Em inglês chama-se Unit Test, ou seja, Teste de Unidade. Então vou responder o que é Teste de Unidade.

E não existe "teste integrado", mesmo que algumas chamem assim. Até existe, mas não é o que quer saber. Qualquer tipo de teste que seja integrado com alguma coisa é um teste integrado. O termo correto aqui é Teste de Integração. Integration Test tem tradução fácil, não deveria ser sido usado de forma equivocada.

Se não usarmos os nomes corretos, todo o resto será entendido errado ou não entendido. E não duvide que grande parte das pessoas fazem os testes errados, em parte porque sequer sabem falar o nome deles.

Não que eu ache a Wikipedia uma referência canônica confiável, mas veja como eles chamados https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_unidade e https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o.

## Teste de Unidade

É o teste usado para testar unidades do código. O termo unidade é usado porque exatamente o que ela é, não está definido, pode ser uma função, um tipo, um módulo, o que for. Embora na prática quase todos os testes sejam feitos em cima de funções.

Geralmente escreve-se vários testes para cada unidade. É importante tentar reproduzir as diversas ações que podem ser tentadas naquela unidade.

Não só deve-se testar em condições que dará certo e produzirá os resultados esperados em diversas combinações de uso, mas também testar o que acontece quando as condições não são adequadas para produzir um resultado correto e algo deve acontecer indicando isso, portanto até o erro deve ser testado.

De fato, testar o erro é mais importante que testar o acerto.

Eles existem para confirmar a especificação estabelecida na aplicação para aquela unidade. E acontece muito da formalização da especificação em muitas metodologias ocorrer no código do Teste de Unidade.

Em muitos casos os testes são escritos antes do código justamente por ser a especificação. E também uma forma de forçar um melhor planejamento do código para que ele seja testável. Isso ocorre principalmente em algo chamado [TDD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199885/101).

Em muitos outros casos os testes são criados para evitar o efeito chamado [regressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286892/101). Então quando você identifica que algo acontecerá se mexer no código ou se encontrar um erro, escreve o teste para evitar que ele volte acontecer ou que passe acontecer em uma manutenção.

O ideal é que estes testes sejam códigos muito simples, que não criem dificuldade e que não sejam difíceis de ler e entender sem muito esforço, justamente porque não queremos erros nos testes.

Também o ideal é ter alguma ferramenta que os execute e dê um relatório se tudo está passando nos testes (lembrando que dar erros pode ser passar em certos testes que espera o erro mesmo).

Este tip ode teste pode ter objetivos diferentes. O mais óbvio é evitar erros no software. Mas pode ser também para documentar melhor e facilitar a manutenção, dando confiança (muitas vezes exagerada e imprópria) para o programador criar e alterar seus códigos, sabendo que os erros serão detetados.

O problema é que, ao contrário do que as pessoas entendem, eles não garantem a qualidade do software, até porque é difícil testar toda situação, e até mesmo garantir que os testes estão certos. Por isso é uma ferramenta importante de formalização, mas não pode ser usado como garantia de que tudo está certo.

Há alguma controvérsia, mas geralmente [os testes são aplicados somente à API pública](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251706/101).

Pegando [exemplo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing#Example) de como ele se parece:

```
interface Adder {
    int add(int a, int b);
}
class AdderImpl implements Adder {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestAdder {

    @Test
    public void testSumPositiveNumbersOneAndOne() {
        Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
        assertEquals(2, adder.add(1, 1));
    }

    // can it add the positive numbers 1 and 2?
    @Test
    public void testSumPositiveNumbersOneAndTwo() {
        Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
        assertEquals(3, adder.add(1, 2));
    }

    // can it add the positive numbers 2 and 2?
    @Test
    public void testSumPositiveNumbersTwoAndTwo() {
        Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
        assertEquals(4, adder.add(2, 2));
    }

    // is zero neutral?
    @Test
    public void testSumZeroNeutral() {
        Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
        assertEquals(0, adder.add(0, 0));
    }

    // can it add the negative numbers -1 and -2?
    @Test
    public void testSumNegativeNumbers() {
        Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
        assertEquals(-3, adder.add(-1, -2));
    }

    // can it add a positive and a negative?
    @Test
    public void testSumPositiveAndNegative() {
        Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
        assertEquals(0, adder.add(-1, 1));
    }

    // how about larger numbers?
    @Test
    public void testSumLargeNumbers() {
        Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
        assertEquals(2222, adder.add(1234, 988));
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/UnitTest.java).

Para quase todas as tecnologias têm várias ferramentas e *frameworks* auxiliares para ajudar e automatizar testes.

## Teste de Integração

Como o nome já sugere ele testa o código de forma integrada, e ele testa justamente como as unidades são integradas entre si, é um teste mais amplo.

O objetivo principal é descobrir se as unidades conseguem produzir os resultados esperados quando usadas em conjunto.

Em alguns casos é possível estabelecer objetivos que vão além do simples funcionamento. Não é para testar apenas se dá um certo resultado, mas também que atende todas as especificações, tais como performance e até usabilidade.

Ele costuma ser menos praticado por ser mais difícil de fazer adequadamente, porém sem eles o teste fica bastante prejudicado e perde muito do seu valor. E justamente por isso precisa de mais ferramentas, que nem sempre são adequadas ou estão disponíveis no cenário específico. Existem casos que não é feito com código, ao contrário do Teste de Unidade.

O fato de não darem importância ao Teste de Integração é onde faço críticas ao Teste de Unidade, já que este último é tão glorificado sem muito sentido. É muito comum as pessoas não usarem os testes como ferramenta eficaz, mas sim como dogma. Por isso eu costumo dizer ironicamente:

> Não faça testes

Se não é para ser eficaz não tem por que fazer.

[image: Tranca de porta que funciona mas não é eficaz]
[Clique para ver animado](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2F9zf0asd0c3n51.gif%3Fwidth%3D444%26format%3Dmp4%26s%3D99120b7546978e77da87c40b3c09f5e04fee62ca).

[Para mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101).

## Conclusão

A internet está cheia de erros gritantes. Alguns deles vão para livros. Aqui mesmo, um local onde o conteúdo é classificado, quase sempre por profissionais experientes na área, tem muitos votos em respostas que o nome está errado, mesmo que a definição esteja certa. Sem ninguém fazer uma observação sobre isso. Esta resposta por ser atrasada terá quase nenhum voto e não terá aceitação (até poderia trocar, mas na prática não acontece, a pessoa que poderia não volta) e fica a informação errada prevalecendo e ensinando errado, perpetuando o erro e o validando como se fosse certo. Por isso é difícil aprender certo.