# Teste unitário com JUnit para rotinas default do sistema

Tags: java, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit

Tenho um código Java que verifica se existe categorias padrão cadastradas no banco, se sim ele retorna `true`, se não ele retorna `false`.

```
public boolean validaEntradaDeDadosPadrao() {
        System.out.println("Entrei aqui");
        Categoria cat = new Categoria();
        boolean condicao = false;
        List<Categoria> categoria = categoriaDao.listaTodos();
        for (Categoria c : categoria) {
            if (c.getNomeCategoria().equals("Financeiro")) {
                System.out.println("tem categorias cadastradas");
                condicao = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("nao tem");
                condicao = true;

            }
        }
        return condicao;
    }
```

O meu teste unitário está assim:

```
@Test
public void testValidaEntradaDeDadosPadrao() {

    boolean primeiraCompilacaoDoProjeto = false;
    boolean compilacoesEmDiante = true;


    Assert.assertEquals(false, primeiraCompilacaoDoProjeto);
    Assert.assertEquals(true, compilacoesEmDiante);

}
```

Li e vi que testes unitários não fazem consulta no banco.

Eu quero saber se o meu teste, esta razoavelmente bom, e no que eu posso melhorar para que seja mais consistente.

Comment: Primeiro, precisa mesmo dos `System.out.println()`? Me´todos de validação não deveriam emitir mensagens. Segundo: o teste não faz nada útil e não testa o método de validação.

Comment: Alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não sabe como fazê-lo. Assim ajuda a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

A ideia das asserções é verificar se o comportamento produzido pelo método ou classe equivale ao esperado.

Primeiro, `System.out.println`, como Maniero comentou acima, não é necessário, pois a ideia de testes automatizados é de não necessitar de verificação visual por um ser humano pra determinar se passaram ou falharam (além do relatório final de sucessos e falhas, claro).

Segundo, o nome método não condiz com o que ele faz, ele diz validar entrada de dados, mas na prática o que está fazendo é selecionar as categorias de um DAO, e verificar se existe a "Financeiro".

Terceiro, os JUnits podem acessar o que você quiser (é um mundo livre), mas se eles devem ou não acessar o banco de dados, depende do tipo de teste que você está querendo realizar. Se o que está querendo é fazer Testes Unitários, então o aconselhável é tentar reduzir o escopo do teste ao máximo, testando apenas a menor das unidades. Em geral, para o seu código, um teste unitário usaria uma implementação falsa desse DAO (que em geral não acessa um banco de dados), que permita ao teste injetar possíveis valores, ou reproduzir possíveis exceções que são difíceis de recriar num banco de dados de verdade.

Quarto, tente usar métodos de asserções mais próximos ao que você está tentando testar no teste. Por exemplo, `assertTrue()` e `assertFalse()` são mais claros do que `assertEquals()`.

Por último, em geral você escreveria pelo menos dois testes unitários, um para a asserção sendo verdadeira, e outro para a asserção ser falsa.

Answer (score 5):

## Introdução

Testes de qualquer tipo precisam testar alguma coisa. Esse do exemplo está testando nada.

Você pode testar o que desejar no teste, pode acessar banco de dados sem problemas. Claro que não é o ideal porque testes devem, idealmente, rodar muito rápido e não ter muitas dependências.

Para fazer testes significativos e eficazes é preciso um *design* da aplicação muito bom antes de mais nada. A minha experiência mostra que só consegue fazer testes que valem alguma coisa quando o programador já consegue produzir bons códigos. Não que não se possa tentar, mas códigos cheios de falhas indicam que o programador não chegou no nível de entender tudo o que é necessário para produzir testes. Uma dessas falhas é não separar bem as responsabilidades. Outra é entender o funcionamento de uma linguagem, de como funciona o computador, o entendimento completo da matemática básica.

Então vamos lá.

## Seu exemplo

Métodos não devem misturar responsabilidades. Se ele é um validador ele não deve emitir mensagens para o usuário, isso é responsabilidade de outra coisa, em outra classe. Um validador só deve testar condições e dizer se está certo ou não.

Eu imagino que o método `listaTodos()` acesse o banco de dados. Para facilitar o teste precisa ter uma forma de chamar um método que simule o resultado de forma controlada, rápida e sem dependências. Uma das formas é usar [injeção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101). Outra é substituir completamente a classe do objeto `categoriaDao` por uma versão que não acesse o banco de dados e sim gere um resultado facilmente testável.

Existem [técnicas específicas para substituição do comportamento normal de um método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36756/101).

Se optar pelo DI ([*dependency injection*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101)) é bem fácil, basta receber o objeto por um parâmetro. Particularmente não gosto de mudar um método só para testar, eu prefiro uma solução mais global. Mas é uma opção, aí teria que repensar todo o código de todas as classes para ficarem adequados para o teste.

Dando uma melhorada em outros pontos o método ficaria assim:

```
public boolean validaEntradaDeDadosPadrao() {
    for (Categoria c : categoriaDao.listaTodos()) {
        if (c.getNomeCategoria().equals("Financeiro")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Preferi não trocar o nome do método porque não conheço a especificação do problema, mas ele parece errado.

Aí podemos fazer o teste (não digo que é a melhor forma, mas uma possibilidade de melhora). Vou postar aqui uma forma aproximada:

```
class Dao {
    public List<Categoria> listaTodos() {
        list<Categoria> lista = new List<>();
        lista.Add(new Categoria("Financeiro")); //claro que é mais complexo que isto
        lista.Add(new Categoria("OutraCategoria"));
        return lista; //nenhum banco de dados é acessado e provê os dados necessários
    }
}
```

Essa classe seria a substituta da original que acessa o banco de dados. Claro que seria mais complexo que isso.

Aqui teria que criar infraestrutura para testar de formas diferentes, provocar situações diferentes, criar situação que gere um resultado ou outro, que possa forçar um erro, fazer o código executar de todas formas possíveis.

```
@Test
public void testValidaEntradaDeDadosPadrao() {
    Assert.assertEquals(validaEntradaDeDadosPadrao(), true);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Test.java).

Aqui sim está testando alguma coisa útil.

Bem, é mais ou menos isso. A intenção não é produzir o teste pronto para uso, até porque os dados da pergunta não permite isso, mas sim dar uma informação básica de que o teste é feito de outra forma.

[Teste unitário é o termo errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/567879/101).