# Teste com junit

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

Desenvolvi um simples sistema bancario, agora quero saber como posso usar Junit apenas nos metodos sacar e depositar.

```
 package CaixaEletronico;

 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Caixa {
     public static void main(String[] args){
         // Declarando as variáveis
         String nome;
         double inicial;
         Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
         Random numero = new Random();
         int conta = 1 + numero.nextInt(9999);

         //Obtendo os dados
         System.out.println("Cadastrando novo cliente.");
         System.out.print("Ente com seu nome: ");
         nome = entrada.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Entre com o valor inicial depositado na conta: ");
         inicial = entrada.nextDouble();

         //Criando a conta
         Conta minhaConta = new Conta(nome, conta, inicial);
         minhaConta.iniciar();
     }
 }
```

---

```
 package CaixaEletronico;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Conta {
     private String nome;
     private int conta, saques;
     private double saldo;
     Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

     public Conta(String nome, int conta, double saldo_inicial){
         this.nome=nome;
         this.conta=conta;
         saldo=saldo_inicial;
         saques=0;
     }

     public void extrato(){
         System.out.println("\tEXTRATO");
         System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
         System.out.println("Número da conta: " + this.conta);
         System.out.printf("Saldo atual: %.2f\n",this.saldo);
         System.out.println("Saques realizados hoje: " + this.saques + "\n");

     }

     public void sacar(double valor){
         if(saldo >= valor){
             saldo -= valor;
             saques++;
             System.out.println("Sacado: " + valor);
             System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
         } else {
             System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente. Faça um depósito\n");
         }
     }

     public void depositar(double valor)
     {
         saldo += valor;
         System.out.println("Depositado: " + valor);
         System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
     }

     public void iniciar(){
         int opcao;

         do{
             exibeMenu();
             opcao = entrada.nextInt();
             escolheOpcao(opcao);
         }while(opcao!=4);
     }

     public void exibeMenu(){

         System.out.println("\t Escolha a opção desejada");
         System.out.println("1 - Consultar Extrato");
         System.out.println("2 - Sacar");
         System.out.println("3 - Depositar");
         System.out.println("4 - Sair\n");
         System.out.print("Opção: ");

     }

     public void escolheOpcao(int opcao){
         double valor;

         switch( opcao ){
             case 1:    
                     extrato();
                     break;
             case 2: 
                     if(saques<3){
                         System.out.print("Quanto deseja sacar: ");
                         valor = entrada.nextDouble();
                         sacar(valor);
                     } else{
                         System.out.println("Limite de saques diários atingidos.\n");
                     }
                     break;

             case 3:
                     System.out.print("Quanto deseja depositar: ");
                     valor = entrada.nextDouble();
                     depositar(valor);
                     break;

             case 4: 
                     System.out.println("Sistema encerrado.");
                     break;

             default:
                     System.out.println("Opção inválida");
         }
     }
 }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138341/teste-unit%C3%A1rio-com-junit-para-rotinas-default-do-sistema?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, você pode verificar se o método funcionou como esperado verificando o conteúdo que está sendo impresso no out. Para fazer isso, você pode criar o seu `OutputStream` e configurá-lo no `System.setOut`

Segue exemplo:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ContaTest {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //Aqui você está adicionando o seu outputStream como saída padrão. Quando o comando
    //System.out.println for chamado, o conteúdo será escrito na variável outContent.
    //Dessa forma, você poderá verificar o que está sendo escrito no out.
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        outContent.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testeSacar() {
        //dado (given)
        Conta conta = new Conta("João", 1, 100);

        //quando (when)
        conta.sacar(20);

        //então (then)
        String expected = "Sacado: 20.0\r\nNovo saldo: 80.0\n\r\n";
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, outContent.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testeDepositar() {
        //dado (given)
        Conta conta = new Conta("João", 1, 100);

        //quando (when)
        conta.depositar(50);

        //então (then)
        String expected = "Depositado: 50.0\r\nNovo saldo: 150.0\n\r\n";
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, outContent.toString());
    }
}
```

Esse trecho `"Sacado: 20.0\nNovo saldo: 80.0\n\n"` equivale ao seus `System.out.println`. Cada println é um \n, no final tem dois porque um é o do `println` e o outro é o que está na própria mensagem. No meu caso é \n pq estou usando linux. Se você estiver usando windows e o teste falhar, substitua o \n por \r\n.

O método `setup` será chamado antes de executar cada teste e o método `teardown` será chamado depois de executar cada teste.

Esses são testes simples para você ter uma ideia de como fazer. Se você quiser testar vários inputs nos métodos testados, dê uma olhada em como fazer testes parametrizados no junit: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests

Comment: Está dando erro, teria como eu realizar o teste pelo  System.out.println?

Comment: Qual o erro? O código está justamente testando o System.out.println. Você utilizou a classe do jeito que está na resposta?

Comment: Sim sim, vou edita o post e coloca um print para vc ver amigo

Comment: O problema é justamente o \n que eu expliquei na resposta. No linux é \n, mas no windows é \r\n. Atualizei o código da resposta. Tente agora novamente com o código atualizado.

Comment: Conseguir, vlw pela ajuda brother

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o problema, por favor, marque-a como resolvida.