# Como implementar testes unitários para Clipper?

Tags: testes, testes-de-unidade, clipper, harbour

Possuo um sistema legado desenvolvido em **Clipper**, uma linguagem de programação antiga, semelhante ao C e que teve suporte descontinuado há pelo menos 20 anos, sendo mantida até hoje pelo projeto **[xHarbour](http://www.xharbour.com/)**, o qual fornece o compilador atual para Clipper.

Eu gostaria de implementar testes unitários nas próximas funcionalidades que serão desenvolvidas em Clipper, mas não conheço e não encontrei nenhuma ferramenta para esta finalidade, semelhante ao **JUnit** do Java.

Alguém conhece uma alternativa?

Comment: É semelhante ao C++? Eu trabalho com isso há mais de 30 anos e nunca vi essa semelhança. Você talvez será o primeiro clippeiro a fazer teste de unidade, então tem que fazer tudo na mão. O [Harbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(software)) tem recebido mais atenção que o xHB.

Comment: C++ não tem nada a ver com Clipper. Achei curioso estar usando xHarbour hoje em dia, visto que hoje o Harbour ganhou uma tração muito maior. Quanto ao que foi perguntado, acho que o mais simples é fazer um .prg de testes e linkar condicionalmente, usando uma Init Procedure mesmo para chamar as funções e comparar com o que espera. Pode não ser tão "automático", mas é simples de manter. Complementarmente, pode criar um monte de ASSERT no código, e eliminar do produto final com um #xtranslate ASSERT => (vazio)

Comment: Caramba trabalhei muito tempo com Clipper, nem imaginava que algum lugar ainda trabalhasse com esse tipo de linguagem. E definitivamente Clipper não tem nada a ver com C++.

Comment: @AndréLuisMarmo linguagens xBase ainda estão entre as mais usadas em aplicativos no Brasil. Pouco em desenvolvimento novo, mas muito em legado. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei o [hbunit](https://github.com/endersonmaia/hbunit). Não sei se é bom, se funciona, ou como usa, mas parece fácil pegar com o que tem no repositório, só posso dar minha opinião que não gosto do estilo de código adotado nesse projeto.

[O termo teste unitário está errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/567879/101).