# Como evitar condição de vitória muito grande em jogo da velha?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Fiz um jogo da velha que verifica as condições de vitória do usuário com `if`, entretanto não achei uma solução elegante. Estou tentando desenvolver um método para verificar a condição de vitória com *array*, porém não estou tendo sucesso, segue o código:

```js
// Variaveis Globais
var jogador = 'x';
var jogadas = 0;
//var vitoria = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]];

// Inicia a jogada
function chkJogo(id) {
    var src = chkSrc(id);

    // Muda a imagem de acordo com o jogador
    if (src == "branco.png") {
        document.getElementById(id).src = "img/" + jogador + ".png";
        jogadas++;

        if (chkVitoria()) {
            alert("Fim do jogo! Vitória do " + jogador);
            return;
        }

        // Verifica se deu empate
        if (jogadas >= 9) {
            alert('Empate!');
            return;
        }

        if (jogador == 'x') {
            jogador = 'o';
        } else {
            jogador = 'x';
        }
    } else {
      //  alert('som erro, célula já usada');
    }

    // Verifica se é a vez do computador jogar, caso sim, o computador faz a jogada
    if (jogador == 'o') {
        chkJogo(compJogar());
    }
};

// Selecionando elemento da célula
function chkSrc(id) {
    var src = document.getElementById(id).src;
    return src.substring(src.length - 10, src.length);
};

// Computador realiza a sua jogada
function compJogar() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
}


// Condições de vitória
function chkVitoria() {
    if ((chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('1')) && (chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('2')) && chkSrc('0') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
    if ((chkSrc('3') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('3') == chkSrc('5')) && chkSrc('3') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
    if ((chkSrc('6') == chkSrc('7')) && (chkSrc('6') == chkSrc('8')) && chkSrc('6') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
    if ((chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('3')) && (chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('6')) && chkSrc('0') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
    if ((chkSrc('1') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('1') == chkSrc('7')) && chkSrc('1') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
    if ((chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('5')) && (chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('8')) && chkSrc('2') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
    if ((chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('8')) && chkSrc('0') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
    if ((chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('6')) && chkSrc('2') != 'branco.png') {
        return true;
    }
};
```

```css
#tabela {
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    align="center";
}

body {
    background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jogo da Velha</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jogoDaVelha.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jogoDaVelha.css">
</head>

<body>

    <table id="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="0" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="1" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="2" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="3" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="4" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="5" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="6" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="7" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
            <td><img src="img/branco.png" id="8" onclick="chkJogo(this.id)"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Como pode ser verificado, com inúmeras funções `if` funciona, porém como já disse está repetindo muito o código. Como reduzir essa repetição (principalmente em condição de vitória).

Comment: Veja: [Verificar ganhador de Jogo da Velha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35225/14584). Tem um *if* de validação e um único *if* e um *loop* na lógica de verificar o ganhador. Está em Java mas não creio que seja problema pra você.

Answer (score 6):

Se o problema é ter um monte de `if`, pode fazer com zero `if`:

```
function chkVitoria() {
    return ((chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('1')) && (chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('2')) && chkSrc('0') != 'branco.png') ||
           ((chkSrc('3') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('3') == chkSrc('5')) && chkSrc('3') != 'branco.png') ||
           ((chkSrc('6') == chkSrc('7')) && (chkSrc('6') == chkSrc('8')) && chkSrc('6') != 'branco.png') ||
           ((chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('3')) && (chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('6')) && chkSrc('0') != 'branco.png') ||
           ((chkSrc('1') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('1') == chkSrc('7')) && chkSrc('1') != 'branco.png') ||
           ((chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('5')) && (chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('8')) && chkSrc('2') != 'branco.png') ||
           ((chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('0') == chkSrc('8')) && chkSrc('0') != 'branco.png') ||
           ((chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('4')) && (chkSrc('2') == chkSrc('6')) && chkSrc('2') != 'branco.png');
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Conditions.js).

Também tem como criar um *array* com os valores e fazer a verificação com `for`, mas não sei se compensa.

Não estou analisando se a condição de vitória está correta.

Comment: Entendi, mas ainda está repetindo muito código. Em todo caso vou continuar tentando. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Eliminar Repetição de código não deve ser um objetivo a ser perseguido. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101

Comment: Vou deixar pra revisar mais tarde mesmo, quando meu conhecimento for maior, caso contrario irei perder muito tempo. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: E se fosse um tabuleiro maior, consequentemente precisando de mais e mais condições? Acaba não sendo muito flexível. Sem falar que, se a pessoa for prezar pela elegância, irá querer algo mais conciso (mas isso não deixa de ser uma questão de estilo)

Comment: @Emoon isso é um jogo da velha.

Comment: Quem negativou pode dizer o que tem de errado que eu corrijo.

Comment: @bigown Provavelmente alguém que vai fazer um algoritmo "super elegante" de 15 ou 20 linhas, para eliminar 9 de comparação :P "ah, mas vai que no futuro o jogo da velha passa a ter 20 casas" kkk PS: antes que alguém diga alguma besteira, é evidente que sua resposta foi para o que foi perguntado, e para criar uma situação a se pensar, e não uma disputa de algoritmos genéricos, mas é uma conversa que aqui infelizmente não adianta muito.

Comment: @Bacco Engraçado, pois a outra resposta conseguiu produzir o mesmo resultado com um bocado de caracteres a menos. Mas eu creio que você já tenha percebido isso, né?

Comment: @Emoon eu acho que código não se avalia só por número de caracteres, e provavelmente o Bigown teria um monte de alternativas para postar, mais curtas e mais longas (ao menos, eu teria). A questão é que a resposta foca no que o autor falou sobre diminuir numero de ifs, e foi mostrada uma solução sem if nenhum. Ambas as respostas resolvem, estão corretas (votei nas duas) e a dos loops é inclusive menos performática. Acho que quem deu -1 não sabe muito bem o que está avaliando, esse é meu ponto. Agora, pode ser que a pessoa tenha uma razão legítima, mas aí é só comentar o motivo.

Comment: Inclusive, se a pessoa comentar, tem 2 caminhos, ambos bons: um deles é o Bigown reconhecer algum problema e melhorar a resposta (não posso falar por ele, mas se fosse comigo seria assim). Ou então, quem votou pode ter uma explicação de por que a resposta foi feita assim, e talvez agregar algum conhecimento. Veja meu comentário na resposta com loops, por exemplo. Se o código fosse meu, seria bem mais curto, nem por isso vou negativar uma resposta que está certa. Além disso, há uma razão para o site ter uma pergunta e múltiplas respostas: permitir diferentes formas de se resolver problemas.

Comment: @Bacco claro que pode pode falar por mim, afinal foi o que eu sempre fiz aqui, sempre que alguém diz que tem algo errado de fato, eu conserto ou apago a resposta. Mas acho que o negativo foi por picuinha com algum detalhe que não tem a menor importância, então não tem o que arrumar. Posso estar enganado, mas a pessoa não se pronuncia. De fato dei a solução mais simples, que qualquer programador entende, principalmente para o AP que ainda é iniciante. Como bônus é mais performática. Eu poderia fazer outras, mas essa é a mais adequada para essa pergunta.

Comment: Se for p/ fazer uma solução *clever* eu faria bem melhor que a outra resposta, mas não é o objetivo. Acredito que ele possa fazer também, mas não precisa procurar a coisa mais curta, a que tem menos caracteres. Há uma diferença entre atender um requisito e ficar disputando quem fez o algoritmo mais engenhoso. Eu confio na minha resposta, se não eu poderia mudar para outra.

Comment: @Bacco Concordo que não se avalia código somente por caracteres, mas ao mesmo tempo eu nunca implementaria uma solução mais elegante se ela fosse tornar o código ainda maior (diferentemente do que você - sarcasticamente - sugeriu). E, claro, há a questão da performance, mas isso cabe, a quem for implementar, colocar na balança e ver o que compensa mais segundo suas convicções

Comment: @bigown Fui eu mesmo que negativei (desculpe se isso não ficou claro) pelo simples motivo de que não soluciona o que o OP quer: elegância e reduzir repetições. Se ele está certo ou não em querer isso, é uma outra história; e vai de acordo com o estilo de código de cada um. Ademais, não há nada que eu poderia falar, além do que já falei, para melhorar a resposta, pois aí esbarramos de novo na questão da opinião. Logo, o *downvote* é apenas minha forma de (respeitosamente) discordar

Comment: @Emoon respeito essa opinião sua, meu comentário foi só uma ironia ao -1, pq achei inadequado. Como já disse, eu acho ambas válidas. Endendo que alguém poderia não gostar da resposta dada aqui e votar só na outra, por exemplo. Negativar algo que funciona só pq não segue um determinado estilo, eu acho um pouco exagerado.  Lembrando ainda que parte do volume da resposta dada é mais falta de otimização no código original do que na resposta. Mais além disso: se tem alguém à favor de negativar coisa errada aqui no site sou eu, ainda mais eu q vejo tanto positivo errado. Só achei desproporcional.

Comment: @Emoon quanto ao seu direito de discordar, é realmente seu direito. Mas eu ironizar é uma maneira de me expressar também, em face de algo que eu discordo. Espero que tenha ficado clara a razão do comentário também. Mas de qq forma, se vc entende que é correto, é seu direito votar, apesar de eu entender que a finalidade do -1 é outra (apesar de usado como discordância no site Meta, especificamente). Obviamente que se tivesse tido uma manifestação aberta do negativo, eu em vez de "cutucar", já teria exposto diretamente a razão da discordância.

Comment: @Bacco não adianta, é perda de de tempo, ficou claro que o tamanho é o que importa pra ele, vide "eu nunca implementaria uma solução mais elegante se ela fosse tornar o código ainda maior". Pelo menos ficou claro que o voto foi opinativo e não que tem algum erro. Quem ler verá que é um voto de exagero baseado em uma opinião que obviamente eu discordo. Códigos devem ser pragmáticos, não devem levar em conta o número de caracteres. O que era útil reduzir eu reduzi. Dá para fazer melhor? Certamente, mas tem que refazer todo o código. O AP pode não entender nada da solução "curta".

Answer (score 6):

Encontrei o método abaixo [nesse](https://mostafa-samir.github.io/Tic-Tac-Toe-AI/) tutorial de jogo da velha e adaptei na sua função, como não testei, é possível que seja necessário converter o calculo para string para funcionar corretamente.

```
function chkVitoria() {

// checar linhas
   for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i = i + 3) {
        if(chkSrc(i) !== "branco.png" && chkSrc(i) == chkSrc(i + 1) && chkSrc(i + 1) == chkSrc(i + 2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }


// checar colunas
   for(var i = 0; i <= 2 ; i++) {
        if(chkSrc(i) !== "branco.png" && chkSrc(i) == chkSrc(i + 3) && chkSrc(i + 3) == chkSrc(i + 6)) {
            return true;
        }
    }


//checar diagonais
    for(var i = 0, j = 4; i <= 2 ; i = i + 2, j = j - 2) {
        if(chkSrc(i) !== "branco.png" && chkSrc(i) == chkSrc(i + j) && chkSrc(i + j) == chkSrc(i + 2*j)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: A idéia eu acho legal, vale mencionar dá pra simplificar um bocado reaproveitando o(s) mesmo(s) loops (usar os de linha e de coluna com as coordenadas invertidas, por exemplo). Um loop e 4 linhas de teste é uma das variações possíveis. 2 loops encadeados é outra.